# IOS Facebook apprequests, without using the Facebook dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, apprequests

I am user to user apprequests using:

```
[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

This is working, however I would like to work around the Facebook dialog to display a custom view, and send a NSURLRequest with the access token, uids and other parameters embedded in the request.

I have been trying to debug the sdk to what is sent with the request, but as it is send via the UIWebView, I cannot debug it.

I also tried to use a web proxy debugger "Charles" to see the http call request, but it is encrypted, and if I work around that by requesting from @"http://m.facebook.com/dialog/" instead of https, I get the following JSON response.

> {"error":{"message":"You must use https:// when passing an access
>   token","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}

Is there a way to directly send app request without using the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to directly send app request without using the dialog?

Only app-to-user-requests, and these work only if the target user is already connected to your app.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make app-to-user-requests. But have not found a suitable method or example in the SDK or elsewhere.